# Unpermitted parameters for date_select rails not showing in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

trying to post date_select with year, month and date to database but is unable to. I am receiving the following unpermitted parameters.

Here is the binding.pry result

```
    17: def create
 => 18:   binding.pry
    19:   @timeslot = Timeslot.new(timeslot_params)
    20: 
    21:   if @timeslot.save
    22:     flash[:notice] = "Your timeslot was created."
    23:     redirect_to timeslots_path(@timeslot)
    24:   else
    25:     render :new
    26:   end
    27: end

    [1] pry(#<TimeslotsController>)> params
    => {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"9QH4nSgC9ov2Rj+cm/hruebc94OI63eUWJZoqWL9qzM=",
     "timeslot"=>{"name"=>"5.30pm", "starts_at(1i)"=>"2014", "starts_at(2i)"=>"11", "starts_at(3i)"=>"13"},
     "commit"=>"Create Timeslot",
     "action"=>"create",
     "controller"=>"timeslots"}
    [2] pry(#<TimeslotsController>)> params.require(:timeslot).permit(:name,  :"starts_at(1i).to_i", :"starts_at(2i).to_i", :"starts_at(3i).to_i")
    Unpermitted parameters: starts_at(1i), starts_at(2i), starts_at(3i)
    => {"name"=>"5.30pm"}
    [3] pry(#<TimeslotsController>)> params.require(:timeslot).permit(:name, starts_at: [])    
    Unpermitted parameters: starts_at(1i), starts_at(2i), starts_at(3i)
    => {"name"=>"5.30pm"}
    [4] pry(#<TimeslotsController>)> params.require(:timeslot).permit(:name, starts_at: [(1i), (2i), (3i)])    
    Unpermitted parameters: starts_at(1i), starts_at(2i), starts_at(3i)
    => {"name"=>"5.30pm"}
    [5] pry(#<TimeslotsController>)>
```

This is the strong params whitelist for the controller

```
  def timeslot_params
    params.require(:timeslot).permit(:name,  :"starts_at(1i).to_i", :"starts_at(2i).to_i", :"starts_at(3i).to_i")
  end
```

This is the form

```
<div class='well'>
  <%= simple_form_for @timeslot do |f| %>
    <div class='control-group'>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class='control-group'>
      <%= f.label :starts_at %>
      <%= f.date_select :starts_at %>
    </div>   
    <%= f.submit(@timeslot.new_record? ? 'Create Timeslot' : 'Update Timeslot', class: 'btn btn-primary')%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I am using Rails 4.1.6 / ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0].

The database schema type of "starts_at" is in datetime format.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `params.require(:timeslot).permit(:name, :starts_at)`?

Comment: Can you add your model?

Comment: @Зелёный thank you for a comment under my answer, I've reviewed the question and found, that this is not the same situation I've stumbled on some days ago, so, I've removed the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have **starts_at as your model attribute** add this:

```
params.require(:timeslot).permit(:name, :starts_at)
```

if not add `attr_accessible :starts_at` in your model and then

```
params.require(:timeslot).permit(:name, :starts_at)
```

It will work.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. 
Yes! your solution helped. =)
I think I recalled how I missed that, prior to this, I was using ":starts_at", however the database schema type for it was a string format. When I changed it to datetime format, I made an oversight by adding the 3 params for ":starts_at".